# how to decode phpciphered files?

Tags: php

Any body know how to decode ciphered files. I have phpcipher.bin file and other php with ciphered text. How Can i convert back to php file to analyse php files.

Thanks in Advance,

Alagar

Answer (score 0):

PHP Cipher is an obfuscator to prevent people from seeing the source code. The file is encrypted, and by design you cannot decrypt the code. Presumably, you could if you knew the encryption key, but they say

"Our advance encryption algorithm uses a 128-bit key as well as a non-invertible function to encrypt php scripts."

From [the FAQ](http://www.phpcipher.com/faqmain.php)

"Q. I lost my original source code. Can you restore my encoded source code?

A.  Unfortunately, we are unable to restore encoded source code. Please ensure that you have adequate backups in place."

Comment: I'd be a bit suspicious of their claims: if you can execute it, you can decode it -- if nothing else, to PHP byetcode.  Which isn't PHP source, but it's the next best thing.